ODE INTERNAL ERROR 1 Simulating AUV Tutorial
I am trying to run the tutorial here so I can create a virtual representation of my planned AUV. I am new to Gazebo so no ide ahow to solve it.
[1]:AUV Tutorial
[https://gazebosim.org/api/gazebo/6.9/underwater_vehicles.html][1]
my error in Gazebo is:

ODE INTERNAL ERROR 1: assertion "aabbBound >= dMinIntExact &&
aabbBound < dMaxIntExact" failed in collide()
[collision_space.cpp:460] Stack trace (most recent call last):
#31   Object "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-3.0.so.3.0", at 0x7ca4f9c34c96, in

I see the model accelerating and not stopping even if the command of 0 thrust is send
can anyone please point me if I am doing anything wrong?
I have ubuntu 22.04, gazebo Fortress

I found the problem
The way that the hydrodynamics parameters was represented is different from fossen notation for my version

